# XMPP or Websocket or others for realtime app?

Tags: php, .net, flash, web-services

I heard of XMPP, websocket. I'm confused about what to use. For example let's say I'm a financial broker and distribute real time quotes to client platforms on the web and on desktop in Flash, .NET or PHP. What should I use ?

Comment: How real-time does realtime need to be? I suspect for the type of industry that your in that ajax/https will be the way to go.

Comment: Talk about buzzwords: xmpp, websocket, ajax, https. They're all used for different things, and while related, are not equivalent to each other in any way. "How do I hammer in a nail? Jello or rock?" "Well, I prefer bananas and puppies"

Answer (score 1):

Is this just an example, or the real application?

In trading room environments, market data applications are extremely sensitive to delays of even a few milliseconds, and a lot of time and money is invested to minimise delays.

This makes the set of technologies you're talking about completely inappropriate; C/C++/Java apps communicating over raw TCP sockets or through a high performance middleware are the only way to get the necessary performance. Internet distribution has unpredictable delays.

Of course, if you're talking about the low-end of the market, where 'realtime' means the user won't get bored waiting for a response, as opposed to liveness of data, then there are many possible technologies. AJAX may be suitable, using either XML or JSON payload.

What type of data source do the quotes come from? Is it's a database, XML/JSON AJAX makes sense; if it's message-orientated middleware, then sockets are much better.

Do you need to have real-time updates, and is it acceptable for individual updates to get aggregated?

Comment: Well isn't websocket about using tcp/ip over the internet but with security in mind ? C/C++ cannot work in browser and java has deployment problems for people who are not geeks.

Comment: Yes, but then you're into using an interpreted script on the client, which has even bigger performance issues. If this is a business application, then installing software shouldn't be an issue. Can you provide details on the data source, performance & reliability asked for above?

Comment: Business application doesn't always mean desktop. Requirement is it should work inside a browser also.

Comment: As you appear to know the requirements but won't share them, I'll let you decide the appropriate technology.